# Get and set ForeignKey directly in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to work with Django model created from a mysql database which has composite foreign keys.

My `models.py` goes like this.

```
class Make(models.Model):
    idmake = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    make = models.CharField(max_length=20L, unique=True, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
      return self.make    
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'make'

class Models(models.Model):
    idmodels = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    make = models.ForeignKey(Make, db_column='make', to_field='make')
    model = models.CharField(max_length=45L, unique=True)
    resource_type = models.CharField(max_length=7L)
    def __unicode__(self):
      return self.model    
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'models'

class Systems(models.Model):
    idsystems = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True,  unique=True)
    make = models.ForeignKey(Models, null=True, db_column='make', blank=True, related_name='system_make')
    model = models.ForeignKey(Models, null=True, db_column='model', to_field = 'model', blank=True, related_name='system_model')
    serial_num = models.CharField(max_length=45L, blank=True)
    service_tag = models.CharField(max_length=45L, blank=True)
    mac = models.CharField(max_length=45L, unique=True)
```

Now when I try to access the `make` field of Systems I get a `ValueError`.

```
>>> s = Systems.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> s.model
<Models: model11>
>>> s.model.make
<Make: make1>
>>> s.make
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 384, in __get__
      rel_obj = qs.get(**params)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 395, in get
      clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 669, in filter
      return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 687, in _filter_or_exclude
      clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1271, in add_q
      can_reuse=used_aliases, force_having=force_having)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1202, in add_filter 
      connector)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/where.py", line 71, in add 
      value = obj.prepare(lookup_type, value)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/where.py", line 339, in prepare
      return self.field.get_prep_lookup(lookup_type, value)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1003, in get_prep_lookup
      return super(IntegerField, self).get_prep_lookup(lookup_type, value)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 322, in get_prep_lookup
      return self.get_prep_value(value)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 997, in get_prep_value
      return int(value)
    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'make1'
```

I'm not allowed to change the tables and relations in the database. I'm very new to Django and I'm unable to figure out what is the correct fix for this issue. Basically I would like to be able to get and set the `make` field of the `Systems` model directly. Can someone guide me on how I should go about doing this? My initial thoughts were that I would have to create a custom `ForeignKey` field.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your codes don't match your DB schema. In this line:

```
make = models.ForeignKey(Models, null=True, db_column='make', blank=True, related_name='system_make')
```

`Models` is supposed to be `Make`, isn't it? And your `Systems.model` has `to_field = 'model'`, did you miss `to_field='make'` for `Systems.make`? I suggest you to drop the whole DB, run `syncdb` and create test data again. Then see if the error still happen.

Some more tips for your code:

- as your defined `to_field = 'model'` and `to_field='make'`, you'd better to consider add `db_index=True` for `make` and `model` fields. Otherwise query performance may be bad when your dataset is large
- if you're going to set `Make.make` and `Models.model` to be unique and indexed, they seems to be qualified as primary key. Are the `idmake` and `idmodels` really necessary in your case?
- `primary_key=True` guarantees unique. `unique=True` is redundant
- Django conversions use singular form for model definition. I.e., use `Model` `System`, rather than `Models` `Systems`. Also, usually we use `id`, rather than `idmake`, `idmodels`. Those are just conversions, up to you

Comment: Thanks for your answer @ZZY. I do not fully understand what you mean by `Models` is supposed to be `Make`? In the `Models` table, the field `make` is a foreign key and is related to `make` field of `Make` table. In `Systems.make` I can not have a `to_field='make'` because `make` is not unique in `Models`. In `Models`, `make` and `model` are unique together.

Comment: If you need `make` and `model` unique together, in `class Meta`, define `unique_together = ("make", "model")`. [Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/options/#unique-together)

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the answer, rather by accident. Would like to share for anyone facing similar problem.
To access `make` directly from `Systems`

```
>>> s = Systems.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> s.model
<Models: model11>
>>> s.model.make
<Make: make1>
>>> s.make_id
u'make1'
```

To set `make` directly from a `Systems` object

```
>>> s.make_id = Models.objects.get(model='model21').make.make
>>> s.save()
>>> s.make_id
u'make2'
```

Be warned. This will not work if the get method of Models returns multiple or no model objects. For example if my `Models` table was as:

[image]

then

```
>>>> Models.objects.get(model='unknown').make.make
Traceback (most recent call last):
....
MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one Models -- it returned 2!
>>> Models.objects.get(model='not known').make.make
Traceback (most recent call last):
....
DoesNotExist: Models matching query does not exist.
```

I fell the programmer needs to be cautious about these things.

**EDIT**
From comments by @ZZY to this answer and to his own answer

```
class Models(models.Model):
    idmodels = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    make = models.ForeignKey(Make, db_column='make', to_field='make')
    model = models.CharField(max_length=45L, unique=True)
    resource_type = models.CharField(max_length=7L)
    def __unicode__(self):
      return self.model    
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'models'
        unique_together = ("make", "model")
```

And also since `model` field in `Models` is unique, the scenario described by me should not occur in a correct table

Comment: `objects.get` is intended to return unique result. `MultipleObjectsReturned` and `DoesNotExist` work exactly as expected in that case. If in the table there are multiple records with same query value and you want to get the first one, use `objects.filter(model='...').first()` [Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#first). And in your definition of `Models`, `model` fields is unique. So your DB should not have duplicate value